# Drupal6: Embedding a region in a view .tpl.php file

Tags: drupal, templates, drupal-6, preprocessor, theming

Anyone have any ideas on how I might embed a region into a view .tpl.php file?

I accomplish it easily enough in a node .tpl.php by adding something like this to `theme_preproces_node()`:

```
$vars['promos'] = theme('blocks', 'promos');
```

No problem at all. However, there obviously isn't a `theme_preprocess_view()` function, and I get memory errors when I try to add the same snippet to `theme_preprocess()`.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /Users/cpharmston/Sites/Projects/Threespot/neh01/includes/database.mysqli.inc on line 42

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'Quick and dirty' way:** You could just put the `theme('blocks', [region_name])` call directly into the views .tpl.php file.

While the preprocess functions aim at a better separation of 'business' logic vs. 'display' logic, they are not required in any way, so you can still put custom code in a .tpl.php file any way you like.

**'Proper' way:** There **are** preprocess functions for views, just more than one. Take a look at the theme.inc file of the views module. There you'll find different preprocess functions for the different templates possibly used by a view (e.g. 'unformatted' vs. 'table' vs. 'list', etc.). You just need to find the one relevant for the view template you want to inject the new variable.

Comment: File this one under the "DOH!" category. I was so deep into separating business and display logic that I overlooked the obvious. Thanks for the help :)